# 'true' bool property counter method - is this efficient?

Tags: c#

I have a simple method which checks how many of bool properties of a particular object are true. If there is only one property that is true, it will return the relevant string. However, if more than one property is true it will return null.

```
public class HobbieSelector
{
    public bool Football { get; set; }
    public bool Tennis { get; set; }
    public bool Hockey { get; set; }
    public bool Basketball { get; set; }
    public bool Baseball { get; set; }
}

public string GetSelectedHobbie(HobbieSelector hobbie)
{
    var selectedHobbie = string.Empty;
    var count = 0;

    if(hobbie.Football)
    {
        selectedHobbie = "Football";
        count++;
    }
    if(hobbie.Tennis)
    {
        selectedHobbie = "Tennis";
        count++;
    }
    if(hobbie.Hockey)
    {
        selectedHobbie = "Hockey";
        count++;
    }
    if(hobbie.Basketball)
    {
        selectedHobbie = "Basketball";
        count++;
    }
    if(hobbie.Baseball)
    {
        selectedHobbie = "Baseball";
        count++;
    }

    return count == 1 ? selectedHobbie : null;
}
```

This code will be run multiple times, and efficiency is paramount. So I was just wondering if there are any quicker and efficient ways of checking this?

Comment: It seems to me that an enum would be more appropriate, to be honest... and if someone passes in a selector with both "Football" and "Tennis" selected, why should it return null? It seems like a very odd design to me.

Comment: Your code has one significant inefficiency.  You are setting the variable "selectedHobbie" to a string over and over, but if more than one hobby is selected you will ignore all that setting work and return NULL.  Its just a pointer set, which is not terrible, but it is not "paramount of efficiency"

Answer (score 4):

If having more than one selections are common, counting is not the most efficient approach, because you can make a decision to return `null` as soon as you hit the second `true`.

If you want the highest efficiency possible, use bit masks. You can test a number for having exactly one bit set to `1` using a very simple trick:

```
bool exactlyOne = (mask & (mask-1)) == 0;
```

For small number of items you can use a lookup table with bit masks, like this:

```
public class HobbieSelector {
    private int mask;
    [Flags]
    private enum Masks {
        Football = 1
    ,   Tennis = 2
    ,   Hockey = 4
    ,   Basketball = 8
    ,   Baseball = 16
    }
    // This table encodes the smarts of the algorithm:
    // masks with more than one bit set are "mapped" to null,
    // while the five single-bit masks contain proper descriptions:
    private static string[] SelectionNames = new[] {
        null, "Football", "Tennis", null, "Hockey", null, null, null,
        "Basketball", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "Baseball"
    };
    // Now the entire code boils down to indexing into an array
    public String GetSingleSelectionHobbie() {
        return SelectionNames[mask];
    }
    // The rest is an implementation of "packed" representation:
    public bool Football {
        get { return mask & Masks.Football != 0; }
        set { mask = value ? (mask | Masks.Football) : (mask & ~Masks.Football); }
    }
    public bool Tennis {
        get { return mask & Masks.Tennis != 0; }
        set { mask = value ? (mask | Masks.Tennis) : (mask & ~Masks.Tennis); }
    }
    public bool Hockey {
        get { return mask & Masks.Hockey != 0; }
        set { mask = value ? (mask | Masks.Hockey) : (mask & ~Masks.Hockey); }
    }
    public bool Basketball {
        get { return mask & Masks.Basketball != 0; }
        set { mask = value ? (mask | Masks.Basketball) : (mask & ~Masks.Basketball); }
    }
    public bool Baseball {
        get { return mask & Masks.Football != 0; }
        set { mask = value ? (mask | Masks.Football) : (mask & ~Masks.Football); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you edited it to use enumerations, but the bitwise AND can be simplified with `HasFlag`

Answer (score 2):

I would use *enumerations* for this.

Design an enumeration `Hobby` as an `enum`:

```
[Flags]
public enum Hobby {
    None = 0,
    Football = 1,
    Tennis = 2,
    Hockey = 4,
    Baseball = 8,
    Basketball = 16
}
```

And then, in your `HobbieSelector` class just add a single property called `Hobby`:

```
public class HobbieSelector
{
     public Hobby Hobby { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can set `Hobby` property using masks:

```
HobbieSelector selector = new HobbieSelector();
selector.Hobby = Hobby.Football | Hobby.Baseball;
```

And you can check if `selector` has some specific hobby using `Enum.HasFlag`:

```
if(selector.Hobby.HasFlag(Hobby.Football)) 
{

}
```

Finally, you can implement the *one hobby check or null* using LINQ extension methods:

```
    // This will also return null if there's no hobby selected or there're many.
   // In the other hand, if selector.Hobby has only 1 flag, it will return
   // the whole enumeration value for the single hobby
   // Enumeration.ToString("f") return the enumeration value name 
   // (f.e. "Basketball")
    return new [] { Hobby.Football, Hobby.Basketball, Hobby.Baseball, Hobby.Tennis, Hobby.Hockey }
                    .SingleOrDefault(hobby => selector.Hobby.HasFlag(hobby)).ToString("f");
```